# How to read vtp file in vtk project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vtk

I have vtk example which can read vtk file if it present, but I don't know where I to put vtp file?

Answer (score 1):

If only the file name is passed to a reader, it should look in the current working directory (the same directory that your executable is created in).

Answer (score 1):

To read and print to video a .vtp file use a piece of code like this:

```
filename = 'filename'
reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader.setFileName(filename)
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
renderer = vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
renderer.ResetCamera()
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

Obviously substitute the 'filename' with the name of your .vtp file, like this

```
filename = 'example.vip'
```